# DynamoDB - can i allow duplicate hash key

Tags: c#, amazon-dynamodb

I am new at coding C#. I have a Dynamodb table and I want to allow the same username to be used but different passwords. is this possible? When I try to create a new entry it just replaces the username with the new password, but I want to keep both usernames with different passwords!!

Here is the code I am using
Thanks

```
{
            AmazonDynamoDBClient client = new AmazonDynamoDBClient();
            string tableName = "idcheck";

            var request = new PutItemRequest
            {
                TableName = tableName,
                Item =  new Dictionary<string, AttributeValue>()
      {
          { "username", new AttributeValue { S = textBox1.Text }},
          { "password", new AttributeValue { S = textBox2.Text }},

      }
```

Answer (score 4):

The table key of a DynamoDB table needs to be unique.  To accomplish what you want to do, you could use a composite key, with user `email` as the hash key and `password` as the range key.  It sounds like `username` is the hash key of your table and you don't have a range key, which is why current entries are getting overwritten.  You'll need to make a new table that has a range key, and have a unique range key for each username to have multiple values for a username.

With that being said, **you should never, ever, *ever* store passwords in plain text**. Passwords should be hashed and salted in storage.  One thing you might do is use either a UUID or a timestamp as the range key and the salt of the password, and store the hashed and salted password as a regular element of the table.

Whatever you do, look up password storage best practices, and do not store the passwords in plain text.

Answer (score 3):

At first it would seem like you should use `email` as the Hash Key, and `password` as the range key. That way in DynamoDB, you would be able to have the following data:

```
email (Hash Key)        | password (Range Key)  
------------------------|-------------------------------------
user1@gmail.com         | be655ea0-8332-44db-9319-1e22da74b2b3
user1@gmail.com         | aa5bf017-57e3-419c-acd2-d2f68a73d913
user2@gmail.com         | 48bee58a-07a4-4154-aea4-10a531909184
```

But that is relational database design which thrives only in relational databases. In DynamoDB you usually have limted Querying capability that you may want to free up the Range Key from this use case for a more purposeful one.

Instead in a flat NoSQL Database like DynamoDB, you could do the following, making `email` your Hash Key, and use a `String Set` to store all the passwords:

```
email (Hash Key)        | password (String Set)
------------------------|---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
user1@gmail.com         | ['be655ea0-8332-44db-9319-1e22da74b2b3', 'aa5bf017-57e3-419c-acd2-d2f68a73d913']
user2@gmail.com         | ['48bee58a-07a4-4154-aea4-10a531909184']
```

Do note the following with this solution:

1. Each row/item in DynamoDB has a total data cap of `64KB` but that is roughly 1.7k passwords you can store over time. I think this should be sufficient.